# MT8163 MediaTek chip with SPFT gives this error no matter what I try - BROM ERROR: S_DL_GET_DRAM_SETTING_FAIL

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, device-firmware, flashtool, mediatek

I have a non-brand tablet built with locked bootloader, and I'm trying to flash it with spflashtool. Since it is a proprietary tablet built to be secure, there is no firmware available publicly. I'm trying to do a read back first in order to generate a scatter file by following the tutorial [here at hovatek](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21970.html).

Chip type is MT8163v

When I try to do the readback, or anything else for that matter, I always get this error:

```
BROM ERROR: S_DL_GET_DRAM_SETTING_FAIL
```

This error typically occurs when trying to flash incorrect firmware. However, I'm not trying to flash yet. I'm just trying to accomplish a read back, in order to flash later with correct firmware.

According to hovatek, I should just be able to use the generic scatter [file that they offer on their site.](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-12724.html), or create a generic scatter file using WWR MTK. However, I tried the scatter file using both methods and I still get the same error.

Is there any other reason I may be getting this error? Could different versions of spflashtool possibly work?

Any ideas greatly appreciated... I'm really at a loss here.

[image: Image of error.]

Comment: disable windows driver signature verification and install again vcom preloader driver. use proper download agent for your device https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files

Comment: be aware flashing on locked bootloader is possible with signed images only